# Regarding printing array

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I'm new in C. 
Let's say i have a union.

```
union DP 
{ 
  int c[3]; 
  char a[3][4]; 
  short b[2]; 
}point = {256,258,260}; 

printf("%i",point.a[0][1]); 
printf("%i",point.a[1][2]);
printf("%i",point.a[2][0]);
```

Why does the first print give 1 and second give 0 and third give 4?

Comment: What did you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize only one member of a `union` at a time. Elements of `c` (first member) is initialized here<sup>**1**</sup>. Members of  `a` and `b` are uninitialized. Accessing uninitialized variables invokes **undefined behavior**. You may get either expected or unexpected results.

### n1570: Annex J: J.2 Undefined behavior

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
> ...
> — An lvalue designating an object of automatic storage duration that could have been
> declared with the register storage class is used in a context that requires the value
> of the designated object, **but the object is uninitialized** (6.3.2.1).

---

<sub>**1**: Other member can be initialized using C99's [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)</sub>

Comment: Your first sentence was really short, now it's a little clearer however i would add an example to show what you mean.

Comment: I think accessing the 'wrong' members of an union is implementation-defined behavior instead of undefined behavior. Can't quote chapter and verse though.

Comment: @pdw; See the the reference.

Comment: @pdw: It's more complicated with unions. It was defined a little vague in C99, and less vague in C11. But the intent is rather clear: Unions can be used for type-punning, so accessing a member after another member was assigned to, is usually OK (if this doesn't result in a trap representation among other things). Cf. C11 6.5.2.3 p.4 (including the footnote), 6.2.6.1 p.6 et seqq.

Comment: @haccks, that citation doesn't apply here, as the union is initialized. See 6.2.6.1.7: "When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values." Note that it says "*take unspecified values*": all bytes of the union are initialized, and the "extra" bytes are merely unspecified, not undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you've made a union (quite strange btw), it's quite straightforward to give the reason since you initialize the variable `point` as an array of 3 `int`s (first field of your union):

- `a[0][1]` is the 2<sup>nd</sup> byte of the 1<sup>st</sup> number, 256. In hexadecimal notation, this `int` is 0x00000100, so 2<sup>nd</sup> byte is 0x01 -> value is 1.
- `a[1][2]` is the 3<sup>rd</sup> byte of the 2<sup>nd</sup> number, 258. In hexadecimal notation, this `int` is 0x00000102, so 3<sup>rd</sup> byte is 0x00 -> value is 0.
- `a[2][0]` is the 1<sup>st</sup> byte of the 3<sup>rd</sup> number, 260. In hexadecimal notation, this `int` is 0x00000104, so 3<sup>rd</sup> byte is 0x04 -> value is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Two big problems:

1. The maximum positive value that can be assigned to a `char` is (most likely) either 128 or 256, depending on if it's signed or unsigned.
2. You are not assigning values to `point.a` correctly.  It must be done as follows:

   ```
   point = {.a[0][1] = 256, .a[1][2] = 258, .a[2][0] = 260};
   ```

The following works as expected:

```
union DP 
{ 
    int c[3]; 
    char a[3][4]; 
    short b[2]; 
} point = {.a[0][1] = 'a', .a[1][2] = 'b', .a[2][0] = 'c'}; 

printf("%c",point.a[0][1]); 
printf("%c",point.a[1][2]);
printf("%c",point.a[2][0]);
```

> abc

**Edit**

If your intent is to assign values to `point.c`, you do something very similar to what's mentioned above:

```
point = {.c[0] = 256, .c[1] = 258, .c[2] = 260};
```

or...

```
point = {.c[0] = 256, 258, 260};
```

Comment: I think his intent is to assigning the value to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize Matrixes and Vectors, you have to initialize them one by one, and complete the unusued spaces with zero, otherwise it should not initialize. I refactored your code, try that and see what happens, I'm not sure what is the objective of your code.

```
union DP 
{ 
  int c[3]; 
  char a[3][4] = {256,258,260,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //This will generate an overflow, char characters max value is 255 each (1 byte)
  short b[2]; 
}point;

printf("%i",point.a[0][1]); //This printf will show this value as Integer type, if this compiles
printf("%i",point.a[1][2]); 
printf("%i",point.a[2][0]);
```